# Is there a single word that means "not many people"?

Tags: word-usage

I am writing about beaches.

> There are sandy, **notManyPeoply** beaches.

*notManyPeoply* beaches are beaches with only a few people on them.

How do I say it in one word?

I'm looking for a **positive** adjective to describe that the beaches are not overcrowded.

In Russian it is "немноголюдно".

Comment: Unpopulated, deserted, desolate, bare, unvisited, seldom visited. Type "unpopulated synonyms" in Google. (0:

Comment: presumably OP wants a positive adjective to describe that the beaches are not overcrowded. but "deserted/desolate/bare" are all negative, and "unvisited and unpopulated" are confusing and don't refer to people.

Comment: i cannot think of one English word to describe a beach which is desirable because it doesn't have too many visitors. Maybe "There are sandy beaches that aren't too crowded."

Comment: @hunter, you understand what I looking for. Your case is good. But I search adjective word

Comment: How about "a quiet beach", or "a peaceful beach"?

Comment: Damkerng's "quiet" is an excellent choice, but you could also say a **secluded** beach or in the case where it is for your exclusive use (or the exclusive use of your hotel etc), a **private** beach.

Comment: BTW, if you are talking about more than one such beach, it should be "There ARE ..."

Comment: "secluded" means not seen or visited by many people, so between _quiet_ and _secluded_, you have two very positive choices.

Comment: @snailboat "peoply" is not an acceptable adjective. Nouns placed in front of another noun is common in English, and they  act like adjectives. (Just saying)

Comment: @Mari-LouA It makes more sense to abstract function from category and say that both adjective and noun phrases can typically function in attributive position, in my opinion.  But theory aside, `[ not many people ] beaches` isn't readily comprehensible, while `[ not many people ]-y beaches` is, especially since the OP's creative way of writing indicates that *-y* attaches to the phrase as a unit.  And since neither is acceptable in formal discourse, I see no motivation to replace the latter with the former.

Comment: OK, let English learners believe that "peoply" is acceptable. It's your edit not mine. Agreed that "notmanypeople" as a compound noun doesn't exist either but I was respecting the OP's stylistic interpretation. (Moreover, why is there the need to leave capitalized "many" and "people"?)  I could have hyphenated the three words, but it looked ugly. However, each word taken individually is recognizable and correct, and that is my humble opinion.

Comment: What about **uncrowded**?

Comment: Whoops, missed @Jay's answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to my silly verse, after critiques and down-votes: never mind the words used in it, the **"quiet, peaceful, secluded"** (offered above, especially Damkerng T's *quiet*) are the best choices, IMHO.

> There are sandy, *quiet* beaches, *free-to-roam*,
>
> *Unencumbered* by people, lapped by foam.
>
> Splashed by languishing azure, *beachgoer-free*
>
> *Bather-fetterless* and softly lulled by sea

Comment: I like `beachgoer-free`

Comment: Me too, but I guess these are fit more for poetic use, so my post was downvoted. (0: From more prosaic choices, I like "quiet, peaceful, secluded" offered in the comments section above.

Comment: Plashed by languishing asure?  Then, do the mome raths outgrabe?

Comment: @snailboat - I'll look up "mome raths outgrabe" when not busy, then probably delete my poem, I guess it's horrible.

Comment: @snailboat - oh, that's (in a way) a comparison with Lewis Carroll. I'm honored. (0:

Comment: I like your poem! I do think it's important that you edited in a sentence clearly answering the question, but I think the poem is a very nice and creative way to present your answer. +1!

Comment: "Quiet" and "peaceful" both mean an absence of noise or confusion, not necessarily an absence of people. The more people present the more noise there is likely to be, but one might say, for example, "I prefer this beach, because even though there are hundreds of people here, they are a very subdued crowed and it is always very quiet and peaceful."

Comment: As pointed out by @Kaz in his answer below all these words -- "quiet, peaceful, secluded" do not at say that the beach is free of beach-goers.

Answer (score 4):

How about *[uncrowded](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uncrowded)*? Does it count as positive?

Answer (score 3):

One useful word which says that there are no people somewhere, or very few, especially in a place where people are sometimes expected to be, is *deserted*.  The proper meaning is that there is nobody there. However, it is also used when there are only a few people somewhere, in an exaggerated sense. For instance, suppose we are on a street with many restaurants on a busy night, such that most of them are full, and we see a place with people seated at only one table, with seven other tables empty. The natural thing to say is "Look, that place is deserted!" or "there's nobody in there", which isn't factually true.

"Deserted" is neutral; it is positive or negative based on the context. "Let us find a deserted beach where we can be alone".

Places that are deserted habitually are isolated, abandoned, uninhabited, solitary, vacant and so on; all such words have a different nuance of meaning.

"There are sandy, *isolated* beaches." is not a bad way to express your sentence.

Comment: "Deserted" is good and valid. An "isolated place" is normally understood to mean that it is difficult to reach. While we normally expect an isolated place to be unpopulated, a place could be devoid of people without being isolated and vice versa. Like, "Thousands of people gathered at this isolated spot in the desert for a huge festival", or "Though it was in the middle of a bustling and crowded city, the restaurant was completely empty."

Answer (score 0):

**Sandy [peaceful beaches](https://www.google.com/search?q=unpopulated+beaches&client=firefox-a&hs=7sD&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=rcs&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=3kmrUsitIKn1yAOc74GwBA&ved=0CGgQsAQ&biw=1366&bih=613#channel=rcs&q=%22peaceful+beaches%22&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&tbm=isch)**
**Sandy [relaxed beaches](http://www.israeltraveler.org/en/article/shanti-beaches)** *(you can relax more easily, if you are not fighting for space)*
**Sandy [unpopulated beaches](http://voices.yahoo.com/visit-nations-most-beautiful-most-unpopulated-777681.html)**

All of the above are common idiomatic expressions. Perhaps lacking in originality and poetry but they are typical adjectives used by travel agencies to describe semi-deserted, quiet beaches.

Comment: To the downvoter. Please explain and justify.

Comment: Makes no sense, two downvotes. If a place is peaceful, it means there is little confusion, traffic, and it's uncrowded. A relaxed beach, granted doesn't mean "few people" but that is the inference, as I explained in my post. Also the links are illustrative and back up my suggestions.

Comment: Hi! I upvoted you to counterbalance the silent downvote! I will not delete my comment because the downvoter didn't answer. Your good answer does not deserve a downvote!